# LazyLoading Images with Dynamic Tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to lazy load images with dynamic tabs.  My code is basically this with images in the tab-content: [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab_js&stacked=h)

And I'm using the [lazyload library](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) (I've tried others as well with no luck).

Anyways with that lazyload plugin, it will still load all the images (not lazy loading) in all the tab-panes but I only want the active tab-pane class to load when viewed and the none active tab-panes to not load until active in view.

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
    skip_invisible : true
});
```

And it works, but only when a 1px+ scroll is triggered.  Any ideas or workarounds?  I'm trying a workaround to embed a listener for `onclick` of the nav-tabs, but it's not working because *I think* the tab-content hasn't updated before the scroll trigger is called.  Or is there a better alternative than this for dynamic tabs?

Comment: [Native image lazy loading](https://addyosmani.com/blog/lazy-loading/) is coming in Chrome 75!

Answer (score 1):

Use [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/). This lazyloader automatically detects visibility changes to current and future img elements.

Simply include the script, add the class `lazyload` and use `data-src` instead of `src`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the lazysizes plugin, because it has hundreds lines of code only for image lazy loading. I think in your case you can use a micro plugin like [justlazy](http://fhopeman.github.io/justlazy/). It is [without jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), very lightweight and efficient.

First, you have to define you image placeholders (in this code example for tab number 1):

```html
<span data-src="path/to/image1" data-alt="alt" data-title="title"
      class="image-placeholder-tab-1">
</span>
<span data-src="path/to/image2" data-alt="alt2" data-title="title2"
      class="image-placeholder-tab-1">
</span>
```

It's also possible to use an img-tag to be more SEO friendly. Then you have to set a low quality version of the image as value of the src-attribute. Another option is to use the srcset-attribute for responsive images (see [demo](http://fhopeman.github.io/justlazy/#example-by-custom-event)).

The second step is to load the images when the the specific tab is opened. Therefore the library has a flexible way to load images via custom events.

To make it easy, just add the following code to your tab buttons:

```js
// e.g. for tab 1
Justlazy.lazyLoad("image-placeholder-tab-1");
```